# Cast or convert varchar 'd/mm/yyyy' to dd/mm/yyyy (date or timestamp)?

Tags: sql-server

An import has rendered a date `[YEAR]` as varchar and I need to convert it to a proper date.

The conversion fails I believe, because SQL cannot recognise `d/mm/yyyy` equal to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

How do I get SQL to convert / cast this into a date or timestamp?

```
SELECT [YEAR], LEN([YEAR]) AS ColumnLength
FROM [IDW_Dev]

YEAR        ColumnLength    
10/07/2020  10
8/07/2020   9   
14/08/2020  10
```

I tried this, and this should normally work:

```
, CAST([YEAR] AS DATE) AS AUDIT_DATE
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `timestamp` is a (deprecated) synonym for `rowversion`. You can't convert a value to a `rowversion`; they are binary values. As for what you are asking, I suggest having a look at the documentation on [CAST and Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a demo using the convert function, just because I felt like testing if it worked with all variations of DD and MM in the string.

Convert has most layouts built in, 103 is for British/French format with slashes.

```
SELECT SampleDate
, CONVERT(Datetime2, SampleDate, 103) AS ConvertedDate
FROM (
    VALUES ('1/2/2020')
        , ('1/02/2020')
        , ('01/2/2020')
        , ('01/02/2020')
)Samples(SampleDate)
```